Calendar Dash component outside box
I am facing an issue in my application dash, a screenshot will show it directly :

You can see that Calendar days are going outside the box of the calendar.
to create that, I simple use a DateRangePicker component in my layout
dmc.DateRangePicker(
    id='calendar_id',
    style={"width": "100%"},
    placeholder='Date Range...'
),

if you want more code of the layout, it is looking like that (I have clean it a little to avoid putting to much stuff) :
layout = dbc.Container([
    dbc.Row([
        dbc.Col([
            dbc.Card([
                dbc.CardBody([
                    html.Label(
                        'Some Label:',
                        className='bold-text'
                    ),
                    dcc.Dropdown(
                        id='dropdown_id',
                        options=[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in ['a', 'b']]
                    ),
                    html.Br(),
                    dmc.DateRangePicker(
                        id='calendar_id',
                        style={"width": "100%"},
                        placeholder='Date Range...'
                    )
                ])
            ], className="mb-4"),  # Margin bottom
        ], md=5),
        dbc.Col([
                #other code
        ], md=7)
    ]),
], fluid=True)


I am guessing that the issue is because of the max-width property on the class .mantine-DatePicker-calendarBase. It should work by reseting the max-width property by adding this to your css:
.mantine-DatePicker-calendarBase {
  max-width: initial;
}

